Trying to debug C++ on Visual Studio Code, on Mac
I'm getting exhausted trying to get this to work. My tasks.json is
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

and my launch.json is
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

but when I click on the bug on the bottom of Visual Studio Code to debug, I get the error message
Unable to start debugging. Launch options string provided by the project system is invalid. Unable to determine path to debugger.  Please specify the "MIDebuggerPath" option.
What should I do?
I spent a long time asking chat gpt and also googling for the answer.

Does the official example in the macOS documentation work: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac make sure you installed the command line compiler tools with xcode-select --install

@drescherjm I'm using GCC instead of Clang, but I think earlier today I tried their setup (using Clang) and it still didn't work.

bug on the bottom of Visual Studio Code i don't think this is a default part of vscode, have you installed some plugin? Maybe coderunner? If so you need to look at the documentation for that plugin for how to configure it. The visual studio launch.json is started from the debug tab with the play button

@AlanBirtles The microsoft C++ extension.

Have you tried specifying MIDebuggerPath as noted in the error message? Presumably lldb isn't on your system path for some reason (probably because the xcode tools aren't installed)

@AlanBirtles Yes, but it didn't work (I tried several versions).

You must generate the executable first before run debug, and also you should start this task from your launch.json.
Example:
tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ compile active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                 "isDefault": true
                },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}

launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) M1 Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ compile active file"
        }
    ]
}

where program is the executable output of compile main.cpp.
Remember run tasks and launch when your code file is focused.


I did run the code first, which allowed me to see and click on the bug at the bottom. Also, I don't know what "you should start this task from your launch.json.". Can you elaborate please? Thank you.

In your launch.json add "preLaunchTask":  like in the example, that allows you to compile your file before run debug, you need dSym to successfully debug your app (added automatically when you compile with -g arg in your tasks.json)

Thanks. I added that line but am still getting the same error. I might just ditch Visual Studio Code at this point. But any help would be greatly appreciated, because I want to get it to work.
